# Looking for Sefer שלחן המערכת by Rav Yishak Yosef Shelit"a

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books

I've been searching for the book שלחן המערכת by Rav Yishak Yosef Shelit"a, but can't seem to find it. I hope you can help me find it (with a link). Thank you.

Comment: @msh210 if you can see this. I'm just wondering...what exactly did you edit?

Comment: I ensured that what you were asking is in the question, not just in the title. See http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/15363/revisions.

Comment: for the record, if you click on the link saying how long ago it was edited, you'll see a revision log.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would talk to the owner of a local seforim store (if applicable) as they usually know how to find things like this. I found [this link](http://www.wslibrary.net/catalog/product_info.php?products_id=5150) online, but I don't know much about the vendor and can only tell you that they look legit from the site alone. Also, not sure how they handle overseas shipping if you're not in Israel.

Comment: Yeah, I found that site,but their shipping takes 2 months and costs a lot.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert -- if you mean R. Yitzchak Yosef the son of Rav Ovadia Yosef, I was only able to find record of his Yalkut Yosef, She'arit Yosef and the "Kol Torah".

[This site](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/9005) has a pdf of a sefer by that name, but the author, though named Yitzchak, is not alive.

[Here](http://www.mysefer.com/product.asp?cookiecheck=yes&P_ID=2860&strPageHistory=related) is another text by that name.

On [this page](http://www.dailyhalacha.com/displayRead.asp?readID=2046), Rabbi Mansour quotes a Chacham Yishak Yosef and a sefer, Sefer hamaarachot,
but I haven't tracked down the text. If you are interested, listen to the audio file and, if possible, send an email to Rabbi Mansour and see if you can get the publisher info and call the publishing house.

edit -- I defer to the sefer [found by Shin Tav](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/15369/759). the cover lists "Yalkut Yosef" possibly as a publishing imprint, but the 2 volumes available on that site seem to be what you are looking for.

Comment: Hello Dan and welcome to J.SE! Thanks for this answer, and hope to see you around!

Answer (score 0):

Almost every large Jewish Book store sells it!
 If you live in Lakewood you can go to Torah Treasures, they have it. 
In Brooklyn, Tehilat Yitzcak has it, probably Eichlers as well.

Online it can be found on ISefer, World Sefardic Libary etc.